# Upper bound on spectral radius of sum of two Metzler matrices

Tags: matrices, spectral-theory, upper-lower-bounds, linear-control, spectral-radius

Given a Metzler matrix $A$ (non-diagonal elements are positive), I am trying to find an upper bound on the spectral radius of $A+A^T$ (preferably in terms of the spectral radius of $A$).
In particular, if we can find a simple condition under which $A$ and $A^T$ have the same set of eigenvectors then the spectral radius would be twice that of $A$. I am not sure that is the right approach, though.

Comment: A simple sufficient (but not necessary) condition would be $A^\top=A$. And with the same eigenvectors you mean that the same eigenvector doesn't have to be matched to the same eigenvalue, namely matching the eigenvectors to eigenvalues would ai believe be equivalent to $A^\top=A$.

Comment: In my case the matrix $A$ is not symmetric, though. And you are right, if the eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^T$ are the same, then it's probably the case that $A$ is symmetric. I think if the leading eigenvector of $A$ and $A^T$ is the same, then you could also claim that the spectral radius of $A + A^T$ is twice that of $A$.